# Most recent date and price from multiple tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, max

I have 5 tables:

```
contracts, contracts_data, contracts_anexes, anexes, anexes_data
```

Table `contracts` columns :

```
id_contract |  date_sign
------------+-----------
    1       | 2013-01-03
    2       | 2013-06-05
    3       | 2014-10-12
```

Table `contracts_data` columns  :

```
id_contract | price
------------+------
     1      | 100
     2      | 200
     3      | 300
```

Table `uontracts_anexes` columns :

```
id_contract | id_anex
------------+--------
    1       |    1
    1       |    2
    2       |    3
```

Table `anexes` columns :

```
id_anex | date_of_sign 
--------+--------------
   1    | 2014-01-03
   2    | 2014-06-05
   3    | 2015-01-12
```

Table `anexes_Data` columns :

```
id_anex | price
--------+------
   1    | 200
   2    | 300
   3    | 400
```

Now I need to select price (from `contracts_data` or `anexes_data`) where the date of sign is most recent (max `date_sign` from `contracts` and `anexes`), but not all `id_contract` are in table `contracts_anexes` (not all contracts have a annex), and one contract (`id_contract`) may have multiple `anexes` (multiple rows in `contracts_anexes` table)

For example

- for `id_contract = 1` I need to return price 300 and date 2014-06-05,
- for `id_contract = 2` I need to return price 400 and date 2015-01-12
- for `id_contract = 3` I need to return price 300 and date 2014-10-12

Comment: Add Sample data and expected result and query you tried. The question very confusing as there are two tables with `price` and two tables with `date_sign`

Comment: What if the most recent `date_sign` is in `anexes_data` but the highest price is in `contracts_data`?

Comment: @wewesthemenace There's no mention of highest price, just most recent date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `UNION ALL` together with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
;WITH CteUnion AS(
    SELECT
        id_contract = c.id_contract,
        price = cd.price,
        date_sign = c.date_sign
    FROM contracts c
    LEFT JOIN contracts_data cd
        ON cd.id_contract = c.id_contract

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        id_contract = c.id_contract,
        price = ad.price,
        date_sign = a.date_sign
    FROM contracts c
    LEFT JOIN contracts_anexes ca
        ON ca.id_contract = c.id_contract
    LEFT JOIN anexes a
        ON a.id_anex = ca.id_anex
    LEFT JOIN anexes_data ad
        ON ad.id_anex = a.id_anex
)
SELECT
    id_contract,
    price,
    date_sign
FROM(
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_contract ORDER BY date_sign DESC)
    FROM CteUnion
)c
WHERE RN = 1
```

See **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/444c4/1/0)**.